# Change Image 'src'- fadeIn on button click, fadeOut new 'src' on 2nd click back to old 'src', ad infinitum

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, fadein, fadeout

I want to be able to change the src of an image back and forth between two different images. I have attempted various toggle and fadeToggle efforts but toggle disturbs the flow of the page. 
I have it working to a certain extent but it only works for two clicks. One to change then one back again. 
Can anyone offer any suggestions for a way to be able get the toggle effect without the 'display : none' factor upsetting the flow. 
I've tried various things from Stack without success. 
Thanks in advance, folks - T

### My code

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('.myImg').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'img/after.png').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('#myButton').click(function() {
                $('.myImg').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'img/before.png');
                });
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a if else

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){

    var myimg = $('.myImg'),
    src = (myimg.attr('src') == 'img/after.png') ? 'img/before.png' : 'img/after.png' ;
    myimg.stop().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        myimg.attr('src', src).fadeIn('slow');
    });

});
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you so much. Can I just ask about a couple of things, please? First, the conditional ternary: IF the src is equal to img/after.png, how does it know what value to take after the '?'.  The placement of the stop() method: What is this stopping? Sorry just want to be sure of the logic.

Comment: src = (something is true) ? take this : else take this other thing ;

Comment: the stop() is there if your img is animated when the user clicks the button

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  if($myImg.attr("src")==src1){
    $myImg.fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).attr("src", src2).fadeIn("slow");
    });
  } else {
      $myImg.fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).attr("src", src1).fadeIn("slow");
    });  
  }

});
```

Not sure this is what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/352pbggs/1/)